# opening binary files from SQL using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, binaryfiles

I am saving my word/excel/pdf/Img files in SQL using binary and i am able to successfully save the files as binary.

```
var fileSize = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
var documentBinary = new byte[fileSize];
var u = new UDocument
                {
                    DocName = fileName.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                    Type = documentType.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                    DocData = documentBinary
                };
                u.DocID = ++count;
                sd.UDocuments.InsertOnSubmit(u);
                sd.SubmitChanges();
```

Now, i am trying to open the binary as their document type, and i am opening this from the gridview where i am displaying all the stored files.

[image]

Now, in Gridview SelectedIndexChange Event, i am able to get the document ID, document name, for me to open the file,but i am unclear about how to grab the binary data from the documentID, which is the PK, and how to write the file out.  Here is the method i am trying to make it to work:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int docid = Convert.ToInt16(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);
        string name = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + name);
        Response.BinaryWrite(GetData(docid)); // I am unclear on how to use this method, with the 
        Response.Flush();
    }
```

where, in my GetData(int id) method, i am trying to use LINQ to get the correct binary data through the unique docID like this:

```
var data = from a in sd.UDocuments
            where a.DocID == id
            select a.DocData
```

but i am not sure what return type to use in this method.

Any help or pointers will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private byte[] GetData(int id)
    {
        byte[] data = (from a in sd.UDocuments
            where a.DocID == id
            select a.DocData).First().ToArray();
       return data;
    }

protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int docid = Convert.ToInt16(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);
        string name = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
        string contentType = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = contentType; //"application/octet-stream";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + name);
        Response.BinaryWrite(GetData(docid));
        Response.End();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The return type of `GetData` should be the same as the type of your `DocData` property, i.e. `byte[]`.

Comment: i spoke too soon, but +1 since you made me to revisit the method i had it earlier..private byte[] GetData(int id)
        {
            byte[] data = (from a in sd.UDocuments
                where a.DocID == id
                select a.DocData).First().ToArray();
           return data;
        }